# Java library or public/private key message encryption

Tags: spring-boot, security, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I want to setup secure interaction between my server and clients and I would like to avoid inventing square wheel.

- There is a "REST-Server" in SpringBoot
- Service has many "REST-clients" in Java installed somewhere. I don't control it.
- "REST-Server" generates public/private key pair for every(!) client and shares pub key with client
- every "REST-client" generates it's own public/private key pair and shares public key with "REST-Server". Client shares it's public key along with unique id.
- "REST-clients" poll ""REST-server" from time to time
- "REST-client" sends request in from:

  - `clientId` (helps "REST-Server" to locate right client pub key to decrypt message)
  - `payload` encoded with "REST-Server" public key assigned for a given client
  - `original message SHA` so "REST-Server" can verify if payload was decrypted correctly
  - `client signature` created with client's private key, so server can verify if message comes from authorised client

"REST-server"

- locates private key associated with a client by "uniqieId"
- decrypts and verifies it with SHA
- verifies sender with `client signature` and known client's pubic key
- "REST-server" sends response in form

  - `payload` encoded with "Client"'s public key
  - `original message SHA` so "client" can verify if payload was decrypted correctly

"REST-client" decrypts response using own private key.

Is there any library / spingboot extension that can do most parts of it?

Comment: Standard response: just use SSL/TLS

Comment: What is 2-way SSL... you are right. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus more on the client angle than the server one:

- Some clients can keep a secret (back end / confidential clients)
- Some clients cannot (web / mobile UIs - public clients)
- If a client API credential is compromised then you may have a permanent security breach

This feels like a problem that OAuth 2.x solves:

- Supports both type of client
- Apps work with tokens and never use API credentials directly
- Even if a token is stolen it expires shortly after
- Threat models are reviewed by experts

In Java I would use a respected OAuth library such as [NimbusDS](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt).